# puppet on solaris tries to update vim-enhanced

Tags: vim, puppet, solaris

I have Solaris 10 operating system with puppet agent installed on it.
When I run `puppet agent -t` I get an Error:

> Error: /Stage[main]//Package[vim-enhanced]/ensure: change from absent to latest failed: Could not update: Sun packages must specify a package source

1. I have no classes regarding updates of vim-enhanced on the master, so where is the error coming from ?
2. If I do have some classes that I'm not aware of, how do I specify a package source ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to any classes, puppet "package" reference solving your problem.

Use this resource:

```
package { 
    'vim-enhanced':
       ensure   => present,
       provider => rpm,
       source   => "puppet:///files/vim-enchanced.rpm";
}
```

But, only working if you are using puppet default file server!

Comment: rpms are for fedora, centos, etc. Solaris uses .pkg files. anyway, it's not that I'm trying to ensure vim-enhanced is installed . I simply don't understand why puppet tries to update it

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstand what you say .... 
If I'm can't found what i searched, I usually use "grep -nr" commands in /etc/puppet/[modules|manifests|hieradata|*] ... because I saw strange result: What I searched, grep found in modules/lib directory (in ruby class).
So, please use to "grep" command to search where puppet use "vim-enchanced" package resource.